# Why my Visual Studio 2019 still compiling the last program without changes?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I had created a new project in C # Visual Studio, and when compiling it, the project is showing me the last compiled project. I try to change the form visual and compile again but doesn't work, still showing me the last form visual compiled.

Does anyone already have this problem?

Compiled program:
[image: program compiled]

Changed I had created to compiled again:
[image: changed program]

But, when I compile, still showing me the program without changes.

Comment: Try to manually delete bin und obj folders and rebuild the solution again.

Comment: doesn't works :(

Comment: Is it still _running_? Close everything related to it. IDE, Browsers ... everything. Check Task Manager. Reopen IDE, hit "Clean Project" , then "Build Project". Tell us the result.

Comment: I try to do that but still doesn't work. I had closed everything, delete folders clean project and rebuild again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved that!

Idk why, but the instance of the new form in this solution has lost its configuration of the form.

The solution to that is:

- change the name form;
- create a new instance:
- ~(example) FormScan frmScan = new FormScan();
- reload everything and compile;

Answer (score 0):

Your solution explorer is loading the last cached project. The easiest way is to just close Visual Studio and then open your project by folder.

After that try navigating the folder and search for
**/bin, not just /bin/Debug. All /bin**.

Delete it and try rebuilding the solution.

if any Temp folder you see, just delete that.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work... I had tried to delete folder, clean program, close everything, kill task in task manager, restart the computer, and nothing... :(

Answer (score -1):

Just right click on the project your on and then select Configure start up projects.
Then if it isn't on current, just change it to that.